# powershell remoting suddenly stops working

Tags: powershell, winrm

I ran this script all day yesterday and then half of the day today. Now suddenly it just hangs for a minute and times out with this error:

```
PS C:\Users\me> Invoke-Command -computer devspin -ScriptBlock {$PSVersionTable.PSVersion}
```

[devspin] Connecting to remote server devspin failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the
operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and
that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM
firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more
information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (devspin:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WinRMOperationTimeout,PSSessionStateBroken

I rebooted both (domain) machines, reran remoting setup, there is no firewall.  And on top of that I can run the same command to other machines or from other machines and it works.  It is just these two windows 2012 R2 machines have somehow stopped talking.

any ideas?  thanks

Comment: This might do better on serverfault. You sure on the firewall thing? Could there be software or windows firewall getting in the way? Maybe reinforced by policy or something?

Comment: It is strange that the command works both to/from other machines. That would point to almost some kind of blacklisting on devspin, which would be quite strange. I would agree with Mark and start by looking there. If you don't find anything, maybe try a Wireshark or Fiddler trace on it to see how far the WinRM connection is getting.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was going down that path too. So I went to our IT dept and they had the answer.  Apparently one of our switches or hw vpns doesn't like the default windows MTU size and it eventually fails in certain scenarios.  Setting the MTU size to 1450 magically made it all work again.

Answer (score 1):

Sure glad I went and asked our IT department about this. They said something about how our new switches/hardware vpn don't like the default MTU size windows is set to.  They said to set it to 1450 and it would work.  I was skeptical, but tried it and BAM! it work.   Computers, they never cease to confuse me.

the command I used was:

netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface 13 mtu=1450 store=persistent

But your interface may be different.  Hope this helps someone...